# GAPlugin in ionic framework

Tags: google-analytics, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

i am trying to build an ionic project that uses `GAPlugin` but my code is like this in `index.html`:

```
var gaPlugin; // Google analytics stuff

    if(( /(ipad|iphone|ipod|android|windows phone)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) )) {
      alert('hello world! this is a device');
     document.addEventListener('deviceready', initApp, false);
   } else {
      alert('hello world! this is NOT a device');
     initApp();
   }

 /**
  * init google analytics
 */
 function initApp() {

   // Init google analytics
   gaPlugin = window.plugins.gaPlugin;
   gaPlugin.init(onGASuccess, onGAError, "UA-x-x", 10);  // replace UA-x-x with your Tracking ID
 }
```

I am trying to add Google Analytics in my ionic project and i included the GAPlugin, but i get this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'exec' of undefined`

Anyone have a clue what might be the problem?

Comment: Do you have any context for where that exception is getting thrown? Also, is there any reason you tagged this Phaser? Unless that's where the error is being thrown, I think you can remove that tag, if you only included it because you're using that framework.

Comment: The exception is getting thrown at `gaPlugin.init(onGASuccess, onGAError, "UA-x-x", 10);  // replace UA-x-x with your Tracking ID` line, when it has to **Initialise** the plugin to the **Tracking ID**...